# What is the difference between "If" and "When" in a conditional clause?

Tags: conditional-constructions, conjunctions

For these two expressions:

> I will give it to you when I no longer need it.
>
> I will give it to you if I no longer need it.

Let us say **it** is an object such as a book or a laptop or something similar.
Is there any difference between the meanings of these two sentences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first assumes that a time will definitely come when the speaker’s need for the object comes to an end. The second makes no such assumption.

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence assumes that there **will** come a time that you won't need the object. So in a certain point in the future you **will** give the object to the person you're speaking to.

The second sentence makes no assumptions and means that only **if** you don't need the object, you will give it. However, you might need the thing and the described situation will never occur.