# When/if sensitive people fall in love, they become totally mad

Tags: grammar

> - When sensitive people fall in love, they become totally mad.

Or

> - If sensitive people fall in love, they become totally mad.

I think both are correct but mean different things.

Comment: Yes, they mean differnt things.  What do you think they mean?

Comment: They *might* mean different things - ***when*** implies something that definitely ***did / will*** happen, whereas ***if*** might simply imply a ***possibility*** (that may never actually materialise). But often that distinction doesn't apply, so they're interchangeable.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica if your response were posted as an answer instead of a comment, I would have voted for it.  Is there some reason you never seem to post your answers as actual answers?

Comment: @Foogod: Is there some reason you think it's more important that I should  post an "Answer" than that the OP here should respond to James's question? Bear in mind the OP has already said he thinks the two texts mean different things, so I'm not clear exactly what's being asked here. And since that request for clarification ***still*** hasn't been addressed, I see no reason to keep the question open.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "If" and "When" in a conditional clause?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3828/what-is-the-difference-between-if-and-when-in-a-conditional-clause) See also [What do you do 'when/if'? What's the difference?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/70394/what-do-you-do-when-if-whats-the-difference)